# Matlab R2017b - Transparency violation error while using parfor-loop to solve equation

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

This program is OK with "for", but it will prompt

> “Error using syms. Transparency violation error. See Parallel Computing Toolbox documentation about Transparency. ”

when I switch to "parfor",  if you could tell me how to modify this code that will be better, thank you very much.

```
clc
clear
close all

% parpool(4)
a = rand(5,4);
parfor i = 1:5
    syms x y
    eq1 = a(i,1)*x+a(i,2)*y==2.3;
    eq2 = a(i,3)*x+a(i,4)*y==5.1;
    x = [];y = [];
    [x,y] = vpasolve([eq1 eq2],[x y]);
    disp(x);
end
```

Comment: Read here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/transparency.html

Comment: @Ander Um, you certainly can display inside a `parfor` - not sure what restriction you're thinking of?

Comment: @Edric my bad. Have you always been able to in all MATLAB releases? For some reason I had a very clear idea that you could not. I may have been just plainly wrong always, that could also explain it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri display has always worked as far as I remember - but back in R2007b the output all arrived at the end of the loop. I don't recall which release added progressive output, it was a year or two after that.

Comment: @Edric ah, then I was plainly wrong! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to replace the non-transparent version of `syms` that you're using with a transparent-friendly version. In other words, you need

```
parfor i = 1:5
    x = sym('x');
    y = sym('y');
    ....
end
```